# How to use map and find together in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lambda, arrow-functions

I am trying to create an array of all string which has length more than zero.

```
let sampleArray2:string[] = ["hello","world","angular","typescript"];
let subArray:string[] = sampleArray2
    .map(() => sampleArray2
        .find(val => val.length > 5)
    );
console.log(subArray);
```

As expected, it is returning `[ 'angular', 'angular', 'angular', 'angular' ]`
I wanted it to print `[ 'angular', 'typescript' ]`

I am specifically looking for a solution which uses both map and find together to accomplish this. How can I fix this?

**Note**: Though `filter` is a straightforward solution, I am trying to see if map and find can be used together to get the desired output.

Comment: Why not use `filter` ? For example `sampleArray2.filter(v => v.length > 5)`

Comment: I know filter. I am just seeing if the same thing can be done through find and map.

Comment: You can't do that because `map` returns an array that has the same length as the original array.

Answer (score 0):

`let subArray:string[] = sampleArray2.filter(i => i.length > 5);`

see [MDN web docs - Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

`.find` is not what you want - you want `.filter.`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your map() returns 'angular' 5 times.

A correct syntax using filter (and therefore preserving your types) should be :

```
let subArray:string[]= sampleArray2.filter(val=>val.length>5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the function `map` nor the function `find`.

Use the function `filter`.

```js
let sampleArray2 = ["hello", "world", "angular", "typescript"];
let subArray = sampleArray2.filter(val => val.length > 5);

console.log(subArray);
```